# speed comparison of pubsubhubbub and message based sysem

Tags: publish-subscribe, amqp, websub

What kind of application would be fair choice for comparing performance of **message based** asynchronous publish/subscribe system with **PubsubHubbub** (which is synchonous)?

I developed an atom based application for the pubsubhubbub but that application is not suitable to be developed using the other option. I am worried that the two systems are not on the same ground to make an objective comparison of the speed of Pubsubbhubub based application with message(AMQP) based application?
Any insight on how to mitigate this?

Comment: WAT? PubSubHubbub is a message based publish/subscribe. It just uses HTTP as its transport.

Comment: You are right but it uses HTTP, which is synchronous inherently. By message based, I mean, asynchronous messaging.